# how can I get session/cookies data in socket io connection in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Hello Every One,

```
        Basically I need to get all the session data inside the socket io callback for handshake socket id + session data.
```

Please let know what will need to do for getting session data inside the socket io callback..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This post from the folks over at Auth0 might be helpful: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/